# Color cells right to left in vba loop

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a loop that starts by selecting the range T17:T35 and coloring it yellow RGB(255, 235, 59).

Then looping left adding a count of 1 to the top and removing 1 from the bottom for each column until there are no cells to color.

```
Sub Smile()

Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Column As Integer
Dim Row As Integer

Counter = 18
Row = 18
Column = 20

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:BB").ColumnWidth = 1.25
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:200").RowHeight = 8
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BB200").Interior.Color = RGB(135, 206, 235)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U16:AA56").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59)
'Worksheets("Sheet1").(R[17]C[20]).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("T17:T56").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59) 'Example Row 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S18:S55").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59) 'Example Row 2
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R19:R54").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59) 'Example Row 3

'Do While Counter > 0
'    Worksheet.Range(R[Row]C[Column]:T" & Counter + 18).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59)
'    Counter -1
'Loop
End Sub
```

The lines in the code with comments Example Row 1, Example Row 2, Example Row 3 are the start of what I want to achieve in a loop until the difference in range between start and end points is 0.

Comment: So `T17:T35` is the first range. What is the next range in your loop? Can you show a before and after screen shot of some sample data? Your code has no loop set up and your explanation isn't exactly clear, *at least not to me*

Comment: Why does this have to be `R1C1`? Is this due to a limited understanding of how to fit two variables into `.Range`?

Comment: @urdearboy      updated question to include loop intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let us know if that suits your request.

```
Option Explicit

Sub colorss()
    Dim R1 As Range: Set R1 = Range("T17:T35")

    Do While R1.Count > 1
        R1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59)
        If R1.Count = 2 Then
            Set R1 = R1.Offset(1, -1).Resize(1, 1)
        Else
            Set R1 = R1.Offset(1, -1).Resize(R1.Count - 2, 1)
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Another version that is not missing the last cell for odd start values

```
Option Explicit

Sub colorss()
    Dim R1 As Range: Set R1 = Range("T17:T35")
    R1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59)
    Do While R1.Count > 2
        Set R1 = R1.Offset(1, -1).Resize(R1.Count - 2, 1)
        R1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Well that is cool. No idea on how its happening, but its cool. Thanks.

Comment: Removed the If statement as it was actually useless

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that *'R19:S33'* was a typo and you actually meant *'R19:R33'*.

```
Dim i As Long, ext As Long, srng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A:BB").ColumnWidth = 1.25
    .Range("1:200").RowHeight = 8
    .Range("A1:BB200").Interior.Color = RGB(135, 206, 235)
    .Range("U16:AA56").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59)
    Set srng = .Cells(17, "T")      'start at T17
    ext = 19                        'start with 19 rows
    For i = 0 To ext Step 2
        srng.Offset(i / 2, -i / 2).Resize(ext - i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 59)
    Next i
End With
```